# Write PySpark dataframe to MongoDB inserting field as ObjectId

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I was trying to write to MongoDB a Spark dataframe that contains the string representation of an ObjectId that is the _id of another collection.

The point is that PySpark has no support for ObjectId (Scala and Java ObjectId support explained here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/doc/1-sparkSQL.md) so, how could I insert an ObjectId into MongoDB from PySpark using the Spark Connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I perform a conversion of the column to a Spark StructField that inserted in MongoDB gets automatically converted to ObjectId

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sfunc
import pyspark.sql.types as stypes

udf_struct_id = sfunc.UserDefinedFunction(
    x: tuple((str(x),)), 
    StructType((stypes.StructField( stypes.StringType(), True),))
)

df = df.withColumn('future_object_id_field', udf_struct_id(df['string_object_id_column']))
```

And then you can perform the SparkSession write to Mongo of that DataFrame and future_object_id_field will become an ObjectId.

**NOTE**: the field has to be nullable true, if it's false, the field will become an Object with a string inside.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer seem to be outdated as of today. It really led me to a working version, thank you.

Here is my working version of the code :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sfunc
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# This user defined function creates from an str ID like "5b8f7fe430c49e04fdb91599"
# the following Object : { "oid" : "5b8f7fe430c49e04fdb91599"}
# which will be recognized as an ObjectId by MongoDB
udf_struct_id = sfunc.udf(
    lambda x: tuple((str(x),)), 
    StructType([StructField("oid",  StringType(), True)])
)

df = df.withColumn('future_object_id_field', udf_struct_id('string_object_id_column'))
```

My setup : MongoDB 4.0, Docker image for Spark `gettyimages/spark:2.3.1-hadoop-3.0`, python 3.6

The [documentation for the pyspark mongo connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/write-to-mongodb/) gave me the idea to call the field `oid`, which is needed for mongo to recognize fields as ObjectId type.

Comment: Your code doesn't work with latest version, could you see [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353098/converting-pyspark-column-to-objectid-for-mongo-spark-connector-v10-x) and help with correcting it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you create dataframe from dict.

```py
mongo_schema = StructType([
    StructField("SomeField", StringType()),
    StructField("ObjectIdField", StructType([StructField('oid', StringType())]))
])

some_dict = {'SomeField': some_field,
             'ObjectIdField': (object_id,)}

df = s.createDataFrame(data=some_dict, schema=mongo_schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to this... on v10.1 of MongoDb spark connector, you have to set the option `convertJson` to `true` in the write configuration (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/write/#std-label-spark-write-conf) , otherwise it will be an object with the property oid instead of ObjectId

Comment: Hey could you provide the code that worked for you? Or could you look at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353098/converting-pyspark-column-to-objectid-for-mongo-spark-connector-v10-x) and see what's wrong with the code?