# How to write ObjectId value to MongoDb using Spark connector 10.1 and Pyspark?

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I’m having trouble trying to figure out how to write a value to MongoDb of type ObjectId using the Spark connector 10.1 using Python (Pyspark).

Although I haven’t found much about it online, I have tried the solution in the below link which states to write a StructType column containing a string called “oid”, but this does not work. It instead ends up creating an Object with a “oid” attribute instead of an ObjectId.
[Write PySpark dataframe to MongoDB inserting field as ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458805/write-pyspark-dataframe-to-mongodb-inserting-field-as-objectid)

```
udf_struct_id = sfunc.udf(
    lambda x: tuple((str(x),)), 
    StructType([StructField("oid",  StringType(), True)])
)

df = df.withColumn('future_object_id_field', udf_struct_id(df['string_object_id_column']))
```

I’ve also tried enabling the convertJson write option mentioned in the below reference, but that doesn’t seem to make any difference either.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/write/#std-label-spark-write-conf